# ItemsSource into ComboBox with Linq (WPF)

Tags: wpf, linq, combobox, datacontext, itemssource

I want to set as datasource into my ComboBox below query.

```
cbLJoin.ItemsSource = (from ud in dataContext.UserDatas
                     join a in dataContext2.Autos
                     on ud.Id equals a.Id
                     select new
                     {
                         ud.Id,
                         ud.LastName,
                         a.AutoName,
                         a.Color
                     }).ToList();
```

But I got error.

[image]

**UPDATED**, results into ComboBox:

[image]

Comment: try to store the linq result into some variable and then assign this to itemsource.

Comment: You can't join `dataContext` with `dataContext2`, which is exactly what the error tells you.

Comment: so how can I join 2 datacontext? it's other way to do it?

Comment: The issue is unrelated to all currently specified tags. Please use `entity-framework` or `linq-to-sql` depending on ORM used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can't join 2 datacontext in one query.
You could make 2 queries and join result of them.
Can not test but I think it should work.

```
var users = (from ud in dataContext.UserDatas
                 select new
                 {
                     ud.Id,
                     ud.LastName
                 }).ToList();

var autos = (from  a in dataContext2.Autos
                select new
                {
                    a.Id,
                    a.AutoName,
                    a.Color
                }).ToList();

var result = (  from ud in users
                    join a in autos on ud.Id equals a.Id
                    select new
                    {
                        ud.Id,
                        ud.LastName,
                        a.AutoName,
                        a.Color
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: one more: why result after binding to combobox have result as on screen shot (updated post)

Comment: Then what is your problem with that data source?

Comment: I did like : cbLJoin.ItemsSource = result.........and result show up like on screen.....but should be just: 1, Abc, Kia, Red

Comment: It will be that. As i know, combobox will have Value Field and Display Field.  You could assign Value field = Id, and Display Field = LastName or AutoName...